# C++ Matching Brackets 2 Solution not working

Tags: c++

This problem which is similar to another that I solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983807/c-matching-brackets-solution) is giving me a wrong answer even though the algorithm works on the sample case.I have initialized all the variables this time and it works on a modified version of my previous algorithm.

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <n ;++i) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int four_count = 0, two_count = 0, three_long=0, one_long = 0 , max1_long = 0 ,max3_long = 0,a_depth = 0,max_depth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == 3) {
            if (arr[i+1] == 1) {
                ++a_depth;
                if (a_depth > max_depth) {
                    max_depth = a_depth;
                } 
            }
            ++four_count;
            three_long += 2; 
        }
        if (arr[i] == 1) {
            if (arr[i+1] == 3) {
                ++a_depth;
                if (a_depth > max_depth) {
                    max_depth = a_depth;
                } 
            }
            ++two_count;
            one_long += 2 ; 
        }
        if (arr[i] == 2) {
            if (arr[i+1] == 4 && i < n-1) {
                --a_depth;
            }
            --two_count;  
        }
        if (arr[i] == 4) {
            if (arr[i+1] == 2 && i < n-1){
                --a_depth;
            }
            --four_count;
        }
        if (four_count == 0 && two_count == 0) {
            if (three_long >= one_long) {
                if (three_long > max3_long) {
                    max3_long = three_long+one_long;
                }
                three_long = 0;
                one_long = 0; 
            }
            else {
                if (one_long > max1_long) {
                    max1_long = one_long+three_long;
                }
                one_long = 0;
                three_long = 0;
            }
        }

    } 
    std::cout << max_depth*2 << " " << max1_long << " " << max3_long;
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Here is a link to the problem:

https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO12003

Comment: Please note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of C++, even though some compilers add it as a non-portable extension. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Also, if you have an "array" of `n` elements, and an index `i` which is equal to `n - 1`, then what happens when you use `i + 1` as an index?

Comment: You need to give us some input, output and expected output, so that we can understand what "does not work" really means

Comment: By sample case I meant the sample input and output on the problem page linked in the question

Answer (score 2):

In the below code:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == 3) {
            if (arr[i+1] == 1) {
```

when `i` reaches `n-1`, `arr[i+1]` becomes `arr[n]` resulting in an out-of-bounds memory access which will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (arr[i] == 3) {
   if (arr[i+1] == 1 && i < n-1) {

Comment: `arr[i+1] == 1` is evaluated anyway. Every value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of the built-in logical AND operator && and the built-in logical OR operator || is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument. See this for more details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `n` is equal to `5`. That means the array `arr` has the maximum index `4`, because the first one is `0`.

In your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    { if (arr[i] == 3) {
        if (arr[i+1] == 1) {
```

at some point `i` becomes `n-1`, so `i == 4`, then you try `arr[i+1]` meaning `arr[5]`, which is out of bound.

Note that in the comment to P.Ws post, you tried `if (arr[i+1] == 1 && i < n-1)` to fix this. That won't work because there still is an `arr[i+1]` being executed. You could fix this by using

```
if(i < n-1) { 
    if(arr[i+1]) {
```

but that would mean an even deeper nesting of your ifs. You should probably rethink your approach to the given problem.

Edit: Are you sure you mean `++i` and not `i++`?

Comment: `++i` and `i++` do exactly the same for integer `i` when used as standalone statements.

Comment: Your are right of course. Thx for pointing that out @MaxLanghof

Comment: Well I based my approach on the algorithm i developed earlier . BTW I linked that post.I really dont know what is going wrong

Comment: You don't use arr[i+1] in your previous algorithm.